# Wrong value received for a props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-beautiful-dnd

I have a video editor written in ReactJS. I want to add the capability to have silent blocks for audio track.

All blocks are added with drag/drop thanks to react-beautiful-dnd.
Silent blocks (and only these ones) can be resized, thanks to react-resizable.

My problem : Dragging takes over resizing, as when I grab the arrow to resize, the block is dragged and resizing unavailable.

I tried to link resizing and dragging with a local state -> if the user is resizing, disable the dragging capabilites, if not, activate it :

```js
 <Draggable
  key={audio.id}
  draggableId={audio.id}
  index={i}
  isDragDisabled={resizing}
  >
```

And this is the code changing the state value :

```js
<ResizableBox
  width={50}
  height={35}
  resizeHandles={["e"]}
  onResizeStart={() => {
    console.log("-----début de resizing !-----");
    setResizing(true);
  }}
  onResizeStop={() => {
    setResizing(false);
    audio.duration = draggableWidth / (FRAM_RATE * SCALE);
  console.log("-----fin de resizing !-----");
  }}
>
```

My bet is on the value received by Draggable : I think it receives the value of resizing just before it has changed, and so the dragging takes over.
I tried with a ref, and with the prevState, but it works the same.

When I send `true`, the resizing works perfectly, but, obviously, dragging is disabled even when I'm not resizing.

Thank you for your help.

here you can find the complete code of my component :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { moveAudioFromtimeline } from "../../../../../Redux/actions/VideoEditorAction";
import { reorder } from "../../function";
import { SceneItemAudio } from "./Layer.styled";
import AudioThumbnail from "./AudioThumbnail";
import SilenceItem from "../../../../../components/Silence/SilenceItem";
import { ResizableBox } from "react-resizable";
import "./resizable.css";

const DragAndDropAudio = () => {
  const scenesVideoSelector = useSelector((state) => state.VideoEditorReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // const [currentElement, setCurrentElement] = useState({
  //   id: "",
  //   width: 0,
  //   mousePos: 0,
  // });
  const [resizing, setResizing] = useState(false);
  const [draggableWidth, setDraggableWidth] = useState(0);

  const SCALE = scenesVideoSelector.scale;
  const FRAM_RATE = scenesVideoSelector.frame_rate;

  const updateCurrentVideo = (e) => {
    try {
      const target = e.target;

      let lastSelected = target.ownerDocument.querySelector(
        ".activeContentScene"
      );

      if (lastSelected) {
        lastSelected.classList.remove("activeContentScene");
      }
      target.classList.add("activeContentScene");

      const id = target.dataset.sceneId;
      let current = scenesVideoSelector.audios.find((audio) => audio.id == id);

      let data = {
        currentScene: current,
        isPlaying: false,
      };

      dispatch(updateCurrentVideo(data));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  //DragNDropContext
  const getItemStyle = (isDragging, draggableStyle) => ({
    // change background colour if dragging
    background: isDragging ? "lightgreen" : "transparent",

    // styles we need to apply on draggables
    ...draggableStyle,
  });

  const getListStyle = (isDraggingOver) => ({
    background: isDraggingOver ? "lightblue" : "transparent",
    display: "flex",
    overflowY: "hidden",
    minWidth: "330px",
  });

  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    // dropped outside the list
    if (!result.destination) {
      return;
    }
    let updateScenesAudio = scenesVideoSelector.audios;
    let indexSource = result.source.index;
    let indexDestination = result.destination.index;

    const items = reorder(updateScenesAudio, indexSource, indexDestination);

    dispatch(
      moveAudioFromtimeline({
        audios: items,
        currentScene: updateScenesAudio[indexDestination],
      })
    );
  };

  console.log("audios", scenesVideoSelector.audios);
  console.log("resizing", resizing);
  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Droppable
        key={"286aasery"}
        droppableId={"audioDragZone"}
        direction="horizontal"
      >
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <div
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
            {...provided.droppableProps}
          >
            {scenesVideoSelector.audios.length > 0 &&
              scenesVideoSelector.audios.map((audio, i) => (
                <>
                  <Draggable
                    key={audio.id}
                    draggableId={audio.id}
                    index={i}
                    isDragDisabled={resizing}
                  >
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <div
                        ref={(el) => {
                          if (el) {
                            provided.innerRef(el);
                            setDraggableWidth(
                              (prev) => (prev = el.offsetWidth)
                            );
                          }
                        }}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        style={getItemStyle(
                          snapshot.isDragging,
                          provided.draggableProps.style
                        )}
                      >
                        {audio.silence ? (
                          <ResizableBox
                            width={50}
                            height={35}
                            resizeHandles={["e"]}
                            onResizeStart={() => {
                              console.log("-----début de resizing !-----");
                              setResizing(true);
                            }}
                            onResizeStop={() => {
                              setResizing(false);
                              audio.duration =
                                draggableWidth / (FRAM_RATE * SCALE);
                              console.log("-----fin de resizing !-----");
                            }}
                          >
                            <SceneItemAudio
                              isActive={
                                audio.id == scenesVideoSelector.currentScene &&
                                scenesVideoSelector.currentScene.id
                              }
                              key={audio.id}
                              data-duration={audio.duration}
                              data-scene-id={audio.id}
                              data-index={i}
                              itemWidth={audio.width}
                              onClick={updateCurrentVideo}
                              style={{
                                width: "100%",
                              }}
                              className="audioItem"
                              silence={audio.silence}
                            >
                              <SilenceItem
                                id={audio.id}
                                data-scene-id={audio.id}
                                indexPos={i}
                                duration={audio.duration}
                              />
                            </SceneItemAudio>
                          </ResizableBox>
                        ) : (
                          <SceneItemAudio
                            isActive={
                              audio.id == scenesVideoSelector.currentScene &&
                              scenesVideoSelector.currentScene.id
                            }
                            key={audio.id}
                            data-duration={audio.duration}
                            data-scene-id={audio.id}
                            data-index={i}
                            itemWidth={audio.width}
                            onClick={updateCurrentVideo}
                            style={{
                              width: audio.duration * FRAM_RATE * SCALE,
                            }}
                            className="audioItem"
                            // thumbnail={audio.thumbnail}
                            silence={audio.silence}
                          >
                            <AudioThumbnail
                              src={audio.src}
                              id={audio.id}
                              data-scene-id={audio.id}
                              itemWidth={audio.width}
                              indexPos={i}
                              start={audio.start}
                              end={audio.end}
                              silence={audio.silence}
                            />
                          </SceneItemAudio>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                  {/* {audio.silence ? (
                    <ResizableBox
                      width={50}
                      height={35}
                      resizeHandles={["e"]}
                      onResizeStart={() => {
                        console.log("-----début de resizing !-----");
                        resizing.current = true;
                      }}
                      onResizeStop={() => {
                        resizing.current = false;
                        const duration = draggableWidth / (FRAM_RATE * SCALE);
                        console.log("draggableWidth", draggableWidth);
                        console.log("duration --- parent", duration);
                        audio.duration = duration;
                        console.log("-----fin de resizing !-----");
                      }}
                    >
                      <Draggable
                        key={audio.id}
                        draggableId={audio.id}
                        index={i}
                        isDragDisabled={resizing.current}
                      >
                        {(provided, snapshot) => (
                          <div
                            ref={(el) => {
                              if (el) {
                                provided.innerRef(el);
                                setDraggableWidth(
                                  (prev) => (prev = el.offsetWidth)
                                );
                              }
                            }}
                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                            style={getItemStyle(
                              snapshot.isDragging,
                              provided.draggableProps.style
                            )}
                          >
                            <SceneItemAudio
                              isActive={
                                audio.id == scenesVideoSelector.currentScene &&
                                scenesVideoSelector.currentScene.id
                              }
                              key={audio.id}
                              data-duration={audio.duration}
                              data-scene-id={audio.id}
                              data-index={i}
                              itemWidth={audio.width}
                              onClick={udateCurrentVideo}
                              style={{
                                width: "100%",
                              }}
                              className="audioItem"
                              silence={audio.silence}
                            >
                              <SilenceItem
                                id={audio.id}
                                data-scene-id={audio.id}
                                indexPos={i}
                                duration={audio.duration}
                              />
                            </SceneItemAudio>
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </Draggable>
                    </ResizableBox>
                  ) : (
                    <Draggable
                      key={audio.id}
                      draggableId={audio.id}
                      index={i}
                      isDragDisabled={resizing.current}
                    >
                      {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <div
                          ref={(el) => {
                            if (el) {
                              provided.innerRef(el);
                              setDraggableWidth(
                                (prev) => (prev = el.offsetWidth)
                              );
                            }
                          }}
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                          style={getItemStyle(
                            snapshot.isDragging,
                            provided.draggableProps.style
                          )}
                        >
                          <SceneItemAudio
                            isActive={
                              audio.id == scenesVideoSelector.currentScene &&
                              scenesVideoSelector.currentScene.id
                            }
                            key={audio.id}
                            data-duration={audio.duration}
                            data-scene-id={audio.id}
                            data-index={i}
                            itemWidth={audio.width}
                            onClick={udateCurrentVideo}
                            style={{
                              width: audio.duration * FRAM_RATE * SCALE,
                            }}
                            className="audioItem"
                            // thumbnail={audio.thumbnail}
                            silence={audio.silence}
                          >
                            <AudioThumbnail
                              src={audio.src}
                              id={audio.id}
                              data-scene-id={audio.id}
                              itemWidth={audio.width}
                              indexPos={i}
                              start={audio.start}
                              end={audio.end}
                              silence={audio.silence}
                            />
                          </SceneItemAudio>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Draggable>
                  )} */}
                </>
              ))}

            {provided.placeholder}
          </div>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
};

export default DragAndDropAudio;
```